# What language is that? (<%REPEAT...%>, <%OPTIONAL ...%>)

Tags: language-agnostic

This seems to be some kind of lowskilled, so sorry for that...

I've got a script which is included in a html-file. The only thing I wanna know is: which script-language is it? It uses some stuff like:

```
<div><%=MY_VALUE%></div>
```

Therefore I would guess, that this is ASP, ASP.NET or something. But what doesn't fit in this guess I think, is the following:

```
<%REPEAT ...%>
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<%/REPEAT ...%>
```

I'm talking about the `<%REPEAT ...%>`-Statements. I googled and didn't find any result. So does anyone know, from this `<%REPEAT%>`-tags what language it is?

Another hint:
There are also severeal statements like `<%OPTIONAL ...%>`.

Thank you

Comment: Could be some templating engine running on ASP or PHP or anything actually.

Comment: Since it uses `<%` instead of `<?` I would think it's ASP rather than PHP. Notice that it also supports short-hand tags: `<%=` which is the same as `<% echo`, I guess...

Comment: Any hint from the file extension? (or is it plain ".html"?)

Comment: The files a suffixed with ".iwp"... I think, that's some custom extension. The files are generated from a software. Within the generated files, this tags/language I am trying to find is used.

Comment: Looks like some self-rolled stuff on top of ASP(.NET). - Also because it is generated by a custom software and has a custom file extension. Any potential interpreter software around? Or could you ask the creator?

Comment: Yeah maybe you're right and it's sort of an custom templating-mechanism. Unfortunately I haven't got any interpreter software, nor I have the possibility to ask someone about this, because it's really outdated stuff. But thanks again :)

Comment: .iwp extension also points towards ASP.NET

Comment: Can you give any more information about this? Can you share what happens in or around the REPEAT blocks? Any includes/ Anything interesting in the web.config?

Comment: Does the folder containing the source files contain any configuration / signature files specific to ASP / ASP.NET? Example: web.config / global.asa / global.asax ... such?

Answer (score 1):

You are right in thinking that this should be either Classic ASP or ASP.NET

You can have an HTML file in IIS act like an ASP file. Trust me it's all ASP or ASP.NET.